# gitlab shared runner docker does not support multi-stage build

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-multi-stage-build

i am running the following docker file in a gitlab runner

```
FROM alpine:3.18 as alpine
RUN ...
```

and here is my pipeline

```
image: gitlab/dind

services:
  - docker:dind


stages:
  - init
  - build
init:
  stage: init
  script:
    git clone MY_REPO
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cicdtest

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/mytest cicdtest/. --no-cache
```

My pipeline fails with this error

```
Step 1 : FROM alpine:3.18 as alpine
Error parsing reference: "alpine:3.6 as alpine" is not a valid repository/tag
```

I modified my dockerfile to first pull the image as follows:

```
image: gitlab/dind

services:
  - docker:dind


stages:
  - init
  - build
init:
  stage: init
  script:
    git clone MY_REPO
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cicdtest

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker pull alpine:3.18
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/mytest  cicdtest/. --no-cache
```

but the same error persists. it seems that the error is from the fact that `docker --version` prints `Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638` and `Multi-stage builds are a new feature requiring Docker 17.05 or higher on the daemon and client`. can someone recommend how to bumpup the shared runner docker version to 17.5?
`docker info` prints the following

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host bridge overlay null
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 5.4.109+
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (containerized)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.776 GiB
Name: runner
ID: XXXXXXX
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: You have `alpin:3.18` instead of `alpine:3.18`

Comment: @Paolo I fixed the typo but still my pipeline fails with this error :                                                                     `Step 1 : FROM alpine:3.18 as alpine
Error parsing reference: "alpine:3.18 as alpine" is not a valid repository/tag`, not sure the pulling is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `image: gitlab/dind` with `image: docker`

`gitlab/dind` is not a maintained image and was last updated [7 years ago](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/dind).